# How to collect specific GrayLog messages for later processing?

Tags: graylog, graylog3

I am a naive GrayLog user who uses the web-based search UI to find interesting events.  Some of our log messages contain performance information.  For example, we might have messages like:

> SomeProcessor completed transaction synchronization after 2982 ms.

Using GrayLog's Search, I can enter search terms of "completed transaction synchronization after" AND "SomeProcessor", to get a collection of log messages that tell me how long it took SomeProcessor to synchronize.  I'd like to further process this information, for example, I might want to determine the average synchronization time over a particular time period, or I might want have a graph showing how the synchronization time changes over time.

How can I do that?  It looks like [Extractors](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.1/pages/extractors.html) might work, but what if I don't have permissions to create them?  Is there a way I could dump the filtered messages into a CSV file or something for later processing with different tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "[Export as CSV](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.1/pages/queries.html?highlight=csv#export-results-as-csv)" option under the "More Actions" button that enables you to save the messages to a CSV file.  It doesn't appear to maintain the time ordering, so you may need to sort from within your spreadsheet.

[image]